# What type of protocol should be used to communicate with another computer?

Tags: rest, tcp, websocket

I have a site and I want to allow users on that site to send information over to a second computer. That second computer would then take the information and make a physical robot do something.

The front end consists of an angularJS web app with a node.js server so that any device connected to the second computer can make the robot do something.

I'm struggling with what protocol to use in order to communicate with the second computer from the website. I tried using TCP but there were firewall issues and it doesn't seems hacky. I am thinking of either using REST or websockets but I am not sure which protocol is best suited for what I'm trying to do.

Thanks.

Comment: Use REST if the communication is entirely request/response from the client to the server.  Use webSocket or socket.io (which is built on top of webSocket) if the communication is two-way.  Here's a summary of the tradeoffs: [webSocket vs REST api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613399/websocket-vs-rest-api-for-real-time-data/28618369#28618369) and [webSocket vs. Rest when sending data to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45460734/websocket-vs-rest-when-sending-data-to-server/45464306#45464306).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Websocket vs REST when sending data to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45460734/websocket-vs-rest-when-sending-data-to-server)